# How can I view logs in Application Insights?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-web-app-service

I created Web application in App Service using a custom container from Azure Container Registry, enabled File System logging for it, add Application Insights for this app service. Application write logs to this app insights. But how can I see those logs in Azure portal? I open "Logs" sub-menu in Application Insights and see here "Queries". What am I doing wrong?
Why Azure can't provide just full logs in the portal?

Comment: This question is no fit for SO and might be better off at [sf]. On-topic: Application Insights is much more than just a log store. Check [What is Application Insights?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview).

Comment: Please refer [View application traces in Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/nodejs-virtual-machine-vm/azure-monitor-application-insights-logs#view-application-traces-in-azure-portal)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Application Insights` -> `Transaction search`
Here you can filter data by TRACE type and it is your application logs

Comment: Thanks for this. Microsoft don't make things easy do they.

Comment: To see all your log messages for your Azure Function App, do as described in this answer, filter by event type "requests", click on one of the requests, then click on the "view all telemetry" button